# Structure - Add class if element has children

Tags: entries, navigation, structure

I have a structure section which I am using to create a navigation menu.
It works ok and produces the list etc.
I want to add a class to the li element if it has children.

Current Code is:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('navigation') %}

<ul>
    {% nav entry in entries %}
        <li>

            {# Check for entry type / get related entry #}
            {% if entry.type == 'customLink' %}

                {# Link to a custom url #}
                <a href="{{ entry.customUrl }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>

            {% else %}

                {# Link to a structure entry #}
                <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>

            {% endif %}

            {# Repeat this for child entries #}
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul class="dropdown">{% children %}</ul>
            {% endifchildren %}

        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

I want to add `class="has-dropdown"` to the first list element if it has children.

I have tried this:

```
<li {% ifchildren %}class="has-dropdown"{% endifchildren %}>
```

But that does not work. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Methods](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#methods) section on the [EntryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel) documentation page has a lot of useful things for working with navigation for Structure sections. You can use [`hasDescendants()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#hasDescendants):

```twig
{% if entry.hasDescendants() %}class="has-dropdown"{% endif %}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that this solution will even find child entries that are disabled, so you will have the class added even if there are only disabled pages within this part of the navigation tree.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<li {% if entry.level == 1 and entry.children|length %}class="has-dropdown"{% endif %}>
```