# How to build a great multi-lingual navigation with channels, structure, and manageable in the CP

Tags: localization, navigation

I'm working on a complex website with multi locales, channels, structures and different designs per page. And the site needs a breadcrumb path.

My client **needs** to manage and add items the to menu.

**This is a simple overview of the navigation:**

- Home
- About us

  - Profile
  - History *(different template)*
  - Staff *(listing with entry url's)*
  - Jobs *(listing)*
  - etc
- investor relations

  - finance
  - results (with iframe)
- portfolio
- press (custom url to external page)
- etc

So no hard coding. What is the best solution to build this?

I think this is still a difficult thing in Craft. We need something like Navee or Structure (expression engine) to have a client friendly navigation system.

I've tried [CraftNav](https://craftpl.us/plugins/craftnav). But it is still too simple.

Comment: Johannes - any suggestions on how we can extend CraftNav to meet your needs?

Comment: I would love to see a combination with CraftNav and [Link It](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/link-it).

Link to:
Entries
Assets
Emails
Phone numbers
Custom URLs. + a breadcrumb and active state feature and full control over the output HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I'm the best person to answer this having only built one Craft site but here goes.

I've created a **Structure** called Main Menu which has three Entry Types. (Entry types were the key for me when doing this)

A Structure allows drag and drop ordering and hierarchal navigation ordering for parent > child relationships.

1. Entry Link
2. Asset Link
3. External Link

**Entry Link**

### [image: entryLink]

**Asset Link**

### [image: assetLink]

**External Link**

[image: externalLink]

Big, big (two bigs!) NavEE fan here, CraftNav has huge potential to replicate it but it's still a tad early when I tried it.

In short Entry Types were the key for me.

Note: For my own sanity at a later date [it would be good to read this post on how to tell if your Structure Navigation has child elements.](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/structure-add-class-if-element-has-children)

Not sure if this helps but hope it does.

Comment: Does the main menu structure have the option on to have their own URLs? or is it inactive?

Comment: Entry Link just uses the link as-is. The template would be whatever you setup when you created the entry. The External Link could link internally if you wish so I assume some kind of custom route could do the job. I'm sure I saw some posts here somewhere on choosing you template dynamically but I may have been dreaming.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at this post on how to build a navigation (like NavEE, Structure, Taxonomy) using a Craft Structure. It also has some code-example for your template: [Would you use a Structure as navigation over multiple sections (channel entries, indexes and singles)?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/would-you-use-a-structure-as-navigation-over-multiple-sections-channel-entries/1513?noredirect=1#comment2416_1513)